# No reconoce el tipo de informe 2010 en visual studio 2010

Tags: crystal-reports, visual, studio

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un archivo de *.rpt 2010 y lo he insertado en mi proyecto de visual studio 2010.

Cuando creo un objeto con dicho archivo "Dim informe as new InformeLlamamientoAccess2000_03"estoy escribiendo el nombre del archivo no me sale en la pantalla para seleccionarlo como me sale otros informes que tengo guardados y no se porque.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí lo tengo metido en el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un formulario "frmInforme" que es donde muestro el archivo rpt .
Este es el código que pongo:

```
Dim informe As New InformeLlamamientoAccess2000_03
 With informe
                .SetDataSource(dscontrato)
                .SetDataSource(dscodigosTrabj)
  End With
   Dim F1 As New frmInforme
   F1.Text = "Informe Llamamiento"
    With F1
     .CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = informe
              .CrystalReportViewer1.ShowGroupTreeButton = True
   End With
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.
Esperando una respuesta me despido atentamente
Charo

Comment: Si seleccionas el archivo y das al `F4` para mostrar las propiedades, existe alguna diferencia con otro de los archivos que si funcionan?